# scanf produces segfault on the line of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf(n);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I have, and I'm so dumbed out probably missing out on a very basic mistake. It segfaults on the line of scanf.
How would I resolve this problem?

Comment: printf needs a string first. Then the parameters. like `printf("%d",n);`

Comment: No it doesn't. It segfaults on `printf(n)`. The first argument to `printf()` must be a pointer to a format string. You're passing in the numeric value of `n` as a pointer (and your compiler would almost certainly warn about this if compiled with a sufficiently sensitive warning level such as `-Wall` with `gcc`).

Comment: The text-book reason for downvotes on questions is "This question does not show any research effort ...". Could you demonstrate your research effort, by explaining how even while only reading the printf spec you could miss the need for more than one parameter?

Comment: @Yunnosch. printf doesn't need more than one parameter.

Comment: @stark True, i.e. not strictly. But for any attempt to print `n` it does.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is not at the `scanf`, but at the `printf`. As @TypeIA has mentioned in the comments section, this is because the `printf` expects to have a pointer to the format string and not the integer itself. To do this, just how you use the format specifier `%d` while accepting an integer as input through `scanf`, you need to use the same while printing using `printf`., i.e,

`printf("%d",n);`   Notice the `%d` before `n`.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer lacks explanation for the segfault. A good one is already described on this page.

Comment: Thanks@Yunnosch, I have updated the answer with a line of explanation.

Comment: You could probably improve the answer by using the better, more detailed explanation in the comments, giving credits of course and maybe even asking for permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `printf()` like bellow :

```
printf("%d", n);
```

Probably you did a mistake in your `code` before using `scanf`. For example it may be occurred if you copy a string in a uninitialized array that pointing nowhere in memory.

Comment: This answer lacks explanation for the segfault. A good one is already described on this page.